# Why is the intermolecular hydrogen bond between phenol and aniline stronger than the respective hydrogen bonds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrogen-bond

From NCERT class 12 part 1

> [image]

The way I see hydrogen bonding is that it occurs due to intermolecular charge interaction. The more electronegative nitrogen/oxygen due to the inductive effect the respective hydrogen will be more electropositive.

Since the compound cointaining the more electronegative atom (oxygen/nitrogen) has greater respective charges.Then the hydrogen bonding will be greater between the molecules of that compound i.e either the hydrogen bonding between  phenol-phenol and aniline-aniline should be greater than phenol-aniline.